# how to sum values from hash based on keys from a different hash?

Tags: perl

Not sure if that's even the right title for this question as I'm new to Perl, but I have a text file with 2 columns of interest:

```
AB      Volume
100     280
137     250
150     375
100     100
100     600
137     200
```

And I want to sum up Volumes based on AB#, the resulting output being

```
AB     Instances     Volume
100    3              980
137    2              450
150    1              375
```

All I've done till now is to display distinct AB's in the output file, but I'm struggling to get the sum of Volume counts.

```
$isAB{$AB} = 1;
$isVolume{$Volume} =1;
$numAB{$AB}++;

print "AB\tInstances\tVolume\n";
for $AB (sort {$a<=>$b;} keys %numAB) {
        print "$AB\t$numAB{$AB}\n";
}
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: There is the language, "Perl" and the 'perl' interpreter, but there is no "PERL".  See [perlfaq1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html)

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %res;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split;
    $res{$fields[0]}{instance}++;
    $res{$fields[0]}{volume} += $fields[1];
}

foreach(sort {$a<=>$b} keys(%res)) {
    say "$_\t$res{$_}{instance}\t$res{$_}{volume}";
}

__DATA__
100     280
137     250
150     375
100     100
100     600
137     200
```

**output:**

```
100 3   980
137 2   450
150 1   375
```

Comment: better sort numerically... ;)

Comment: Good, though could be made more readable and more self-documenting

Comment: @hochgurgler: Sure, but it seems clear by itself and it's late now here. I'll see tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

Content of `infile`:

```
AB      Volume
100     280
137     250
150     375
100     100
100     600
137     200
```

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw( sum );

## Check arguments.
die qq[Usage: perl $0 <input-file>\n] unless @ARGV == 1;

## Hash to save content of input file.
my (%ab);

while ( <> ) { 
    ## Split line. If number of fields is different from two, omit it
    ## and read next one.
    my @f = split;
    next unless @f == 2;

    ## In first line print header.
    if ( $. == 1 ) { 
        printf qq[%s\n], join qq[\t], $f[0], qq[Instances], $f[1];
        next;
    }   

    ## Save fields of line.
    push @{ $ab{ $f[0] } }, $f[1];
}

## Print to output.
for ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %ab ) { 
    printf qq[%s\t%s\t%s\n], $_, scalar @{ $ab{ $_ } }, sum @{ $ab{ $_ } };
}
```

Run the script:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

And output:

```
AB      Instances       Volume
100     3       980
137     2       450
150     1       375
```

Comment: +1 because its virtually identical to the solution I was about to post. You can get around extracting headers with `my @hrs = split ' ', <>`. Then print them with `splice @hrs, 1, 0, "Instances"; say join "\t", @hrs;`. `join` can also be used instead of `printf` in the last print.

Comment: @TLP: Yes. You are right. I will leave the answer as is but I understand your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add another hash to keep track of the sum

```
$sumAB{$AB} += $isAB{$AB};
```

then in your print loop

```
print "$AB\t$numAB{$AB}\t$sumAB{$AB}\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend using [record like data structure](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/prog/ch09_06.htm)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %res;
while(<DATA>) {        
     (my $key, my $volume)= split;
     $res{$key}->{QUANTITY}++;
     $res{$key}->{VOLUME}+=$volume;

}

#use Data::Dumper;
#print Dumper(%res);

for my $key (sort {$a<=>$b} keys %res){
    my $quantity=$res{$key}->{QUANTITY};
    my $volume=$res{$key}->{VOLUME};
    say join("\t",$key, $quantity,$volume);

}


__DATA__
100     280
137     250
150     375
100     100
100     600
137     200
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to an expressive language. For something like this, I recommend [`List::Pairwise`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aPairwise#mapp).

```
my %sums;
List::Pairwise::mapp { $sums{ $a } += $b } %numAB;
```